# representing an open set in countable union of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

This question was asked in my analysis quiz and I marked every option wrong. I admit I didn't had much clue about this question.

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Then:

A An arbitrary open set $G$ in $X$ is a countable union of closed sets.

B An arbitrary open set $G$ in $X$ cannot be countable union of closed sets if X is connected.

C  An arbitrary open set $G$ in $X$ is a countable union of closed sets only if $X$ is countable.

D An arbitrary open set $G$ in $X$ is a countable union of closed sets only if $X$ is locally compact.

Answer

> A

I marked B and was clueless about D . But now even if I have answer key I am unable to reason open sets with union of Closed sets and also with locally compact and connected sets .

Can you please give hints for A,B,D.

I shall be really thankful

Comment: $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac 1 n, 1-\frac1 n ]=(0,1)$,so B & C are not true. For D, I don't know what locally compact is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we prove that  (A) is true it follows immediately that the other options are all false.

Any closed set $C $ in a metric space is the intersection of the  sets $\{x: d(x,C) <\frac 1 n\}$ and these sets are open. Taking complements we see that (A) is always true.